# Are there any current projects/plans for a VTOL passenger airliner?

Tags: aircraft-design, airliner

I was very surprised to see there's a seemingly underway project for a VTOL "business aircraft" that seats a few people.

http://xtiaircraft.com  , https://www.startengine.com/xti-aircraft

[image]

They assert they've done a 65% scale test.

I realize historically there have been a couple military transport-sized VTOL aircraft, and there's one or two small ones today.

Is anyone contemplating a **regional airliner** or even **full-size airliner** VTOL concept?

Comment: The [AugustaWestland AW609](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AgustaWestland_AW609) tiltrotor is already in flight test and is being marketed for VIPs, search and rescue, and as a helicopter replacement for offshore oil rigs.

Comment: @user71659 - whoa !

Comment: !! Now with BOUNTY !!

Comment: @user71659 the AW609 is definitely an answer to this post IMO, I encourage you to write an answer giving an overview of it, since no one else has done so yet.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [What are the reasons why we do not have VTOL commercial airliners?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/23799/what-are-the-reasons-why-we-do-not-have-vtol-commercial-airliners) which is itself a duplicate of [Can airliners benefit from vertical take-off and landing?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/16349/can-airliners-benefit-from-vertical-take-off-and-landing)

Comment: @zymhan The question is asking for a regional or mainline transport, 9 seats on the AW609 is too small for a regional. It would be V-22 sized and above. Talk about commercializing the Bell V-280 (a tiltrotor halfway in between the AW609 and the V-22) would be a step in that direction, but AFAIK it's been just talk.

Comment: hi @PeterKämpf !  Actually, I don't care about the reasons, nor the benefits. I'm asking Are there any current projects/plans for a VTOL airliner-size craft?

Comment: @zymhan the AW609 is an awesome small VTOL (hence the WHOA!) but not an airliner

Comment: Well, there are always some plans in some corner of every aircraft company. But for **serious** projects there is a massive wall of economics in the way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

US patent [9,475,585](http://patft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO2&Sect2=HITOFF&p=1&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsearch-bool.html&r=1&f=G&l=50&co1=AND&d=PTXT&s1=9475585.PN.&OS=PN/9475585&RS=PN/9475585) describes a **Tilt-Rotor Vertical-Lift Aircraft**. This patent was awarded to **Boeing** on October 25, 2016. The subject aircraft may be anything from a personal aircraft to a regional commercial aircraft for at least 100 passengers.

The two tilt rotors (36) are powered by a number of turbine engines (40) which are fix mounted under the wings. The novelties claimed by this patent are about the transmission of power from the power plants (engines) to the rotors.

Figure 1 - in vertical mode:
[image: a/c vertical mode]

Figure 2 - in horizontal mode:
[image: a/c horizontal mode]
<sup>Images source: United States Patent and Trademark Office, www.uspto.gov</sup>

Of course, the filing of a patent is an evidence that a company is spending at least some limited resources to the subject. However, this does not mean that Boeing is actually developing such an aircraft.

Comment: A fast browse of the claims suggests to me they won't be developing this to an actual aircraft. One of those things where I am not sure if it is insanely cool or just insane. Well worth a look, thanks.

Comment: Great! A jet intake located right in the prop wash! What could possibly go wrong?

Comment: @PeterKämpf, from brief reading of the text it seems that all the engines (the text says at least two) are turboshafts, attached to common shaft that drives the rotors. And the picture does not necessarily indicate actual position of the engines, so they may be either close to the tilt-rotors so they behave mostly as any other turboprop, or close to the fuselage, outside of the prop wash.

Comment: Whoa!  I wanted an example project and you brought a patent!  Unreal!

Comment: Really, I guess this is the closest thing to *Are there any current projects/plans for a VTOL passenger airliner?* ... thanks!

Answer (score 7):

VTOL airliners were looked at in the 1960s. The [Hawker Siddeley HS.141](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawker_Siddeley_HS.141), for example:

[image]

The idea was dismissed for several reasons that still hold today:

- lots of engines which use lots of fuel and are costly to buy and maintain
- massive loss of payload (because of all the engines that are dead weight during most of the flight)
- jet-borne VTOL is very loud (e.g. the Harrier was one of the loudest aircraft ever), and VTOL only makes sense if you can land in population centers rather than out-of-the-way airfields. so you'd run into noise regulations.

Electric motors have one big advantage over the turbines used until now: turbines are inefficient when they run at low throttle settings, so if you use one engine for takeoff and cruise, it's running inefficiently for much of the flight. Electric motor efficiency is high throughout its power range.

Whether it's viable remains to be seen, XTI hasn't published full specifications.

Comment: Electric motors may help solve the noise issue, but weight/fuel considerations remain for longer flights.

Comment: Does it essentially cost "much more fuel to take of VTOL than to take off conventionally" ... ?  Is that about right?    Is this still true with the electric motor notion?

Comment: .. and how come it's suddenly viable (unless it's BS) for a 6 seater?

Comment: @Fattie start-ups and concept designs are under no obligation to be viable.

Comment: how true, @AEhere !

Comment: Whoa - **16** lift jets !  I bet it could conveniently hovercraft around, also!  :)

Comment: Well, they're doing VTOL with first stage rocket boosters, so it may be possible at some point in the future, probably for small "air taxis" first.  The power requirements for VTOL are relatively huge, but short lived, dropping once aircraft gets moving.  Electric might do it.

Comment: VTOL with a rocket is expensive, but a lot cheaper than throwing the rocket away after 1 flight. VTOL airliners have to compete with CTOL airliners.

Answer (score 0):

There probably won't be because of simple economics. (Even I can understand them, must be simple and obvious.)

Basically even a regional air liner transports a significant amount of people on a regular basis. It is not designed for single transports of single groups, it is designed to serve sustained needs. This means there must be sustained ground transport infrastructure in place at the end points for those groups of people to travel to, gather, embark, disembark, scatter and travel to their destinations.

In other words you need an airport with infrastructure to handle passenger traffic. If you have an airport, you might as well build a runway. It is basically a specialized road for aircraft and you need to build roads anyway.

If you have a runway, conventional take off and landing will be much more economical than a vertical one. That is without the extra mass of the VTOL hardware factored in. Thus the kinds of places it makes sense to use VTOL passenger craft and the kinds of places it makes sense to use air liners, even regional ones, are mutually exclusive.

The amount of traffic is either too low for service by airliners or too high for not building a proper runway that makes VTOL unnecessary waste to make sense.

Comment: Heliports are a thing. Aircraft that can transport more passengers via existing helipads should conceivably increase demand. Helicopter ferry service from Pan Am's Manhattan office tower to their airport terminal existed for a short while before an accident put a stop to the concept: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MetLife_Building#Helicopter_service

Comment: @zymhan Absolutely, I am not arguing about VTOL passenger traffic just whether it makes sense to scale it to a point where you could legitimately talk about a regional airliner.

Comment: Ville, thanks for this but - I'm looking for examples of work in progress, on this question.   BTW notice there are two other questions about reasons-for VTOL (see under the question here).

Comment: Smaller airports (basically "tiny" viz a viz today) would be an tremendously major economic change, I think.  But points well made!